# AWS Elastic Beanstalk upload high amount of data

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and i am want to upload 4GB of wordpress website to it.

I thought i will upload it to Bit Bucket & then via Codeship upload it to AWS S3 but Bit Bucket has repository limit of maximum 2 GB.

Is there some way to upload high amount of data on AWS Elastic bean stalk. e.g via FTP or something. Also even if connection breaks ability to resume the upload from where it broke.

I am a PHP developer and not much into Linux server configurations.

Thank You.

Comment: You have 4GB of data checked into source control? You probably need to move most of that into a database, or S3 or something.

Comment: This 4GB of data is wordpress files & not DB. Need to move to S3 and then deploy it

Comment: What is "wordpress files" exactly? It sounds like you may have a large number of images checked into source control. Those probably should exist on a distributed file system such as Amazon S3 instead of in source control. That way you won't need to copy them to every server you create.

Answer (score 1):

You can use configuration files to customize the deployment process of an ElasticBeanstalk environment.  EB offers a lot of [customization options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html), and there are many ways to cover this case.  I recommend have EB pull the files from S3:

1. Put your files in S3
2. Give your EB IAM Role read access to the S3 bucket
3. Add a .config file to your ElasticBeanstalk project in the .ebextensions directory, such as `.ebextensions/web_files.config`

Sample contents of `.ebextensions/web_files.config`:

```
commands:
  sync_command:
    command: mkdir -p /opt/web_stuff; aws s3 sync s3://sample-bucket/web_stuff /opt/web_stuff
```

This will use the [AWS CLI `s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command to copy the files over when the instances boot up.

You might also want to make sure to increase the size of the root disk on your EB instances.